# Load not working undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with the jquery load. 
The following function is working. When I call it directly from html with `onclick="load_content('new')"`

But it will not work if I call it from another Javascript function. It gives me the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
function load_content(which) {
    $('#content').load('html/' + which + '.html');
}
```

With `console.log` i could see that the function is entered so it must be some problem with the first line in the function.

The Call from the Menu is working in the following html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
    <div class="nav-menu">
        <ul class="nav main-nav">
            <li class="item-101  active"><a class="scroll" href="#New" onclick="load_content('new')"><span>NEUES PROJEKT</span></a></li>
            <li class="item-102"><a class="scroll" href="#Overview" onclick="load_content('overview')"><span>PROJEKTÜBERSICHT</span></a></li>
            <li class="item-103"><a class="scroll" href="#Settings" onclick="load_content('settings')"><span>EINSTELLUNGEN</span></a></li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not working here:

```
    var dialogNew = function()
    {
        BootstrapDialog.closeAll();
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.opensync(newPath, 'r');
        load_content('new');
    };
    setTimeout(dialogNew, 2500);
```

What am I missing?

Although it is working with the click it show me the following error as well 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined`

Here the more precise error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at dialogNew (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trackingCore-ecxfviftqracjxhimcuhhhvyddso/Build/Products/Debug/trackingCore.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3:4994), <anonymous>:37:7)
```

**UPDATE**
Found the error. It was a comination of the code from before and my code. I have to become better in debugging. The answer was to reposition the `load_content` function and replace `fs.opensync`

Comment: how do you call it from another js function?

Comment: My guess is you call the code before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: You're not sharing enough code.

Comment: There are many reasons this could happen, add your HTML document too, that'd help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: I edited it. Is it enough code or do you need more?

Comment: I guess you have errors due to those 3 lines just above `load_content('new');`. Comment those and load would just work!

Comment: thats not the solution. it is not working but i also need them anyway. I think jquery is not loaded correctly but how can it be loaded for buttons but not for a function?

Comment: Is your load_content function the first function, before `var dialogNew = function()` ?

Comment: I even tried to create a new function just above the dialogNew but it is not working. I think jquery is not loaded correctly. But have can it be loaded for a button on the page but not for the function within that html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume,

you call the function in one js file and the function is in another js file. Make sure that calling js is loaded after the js file which contains the definition.

Comment: I have used the function just before. So i guess it hould be loaded. As I said. I works from a button click but not from within another function. Do i have to add it to the other function as well? I would rather like to reuse it.

Comment: can you try with, $(document).ready( function() {setTimeout(dialogNew,2500)});

Answer (score 0):

If You're using jQuery why note make this more elegant way?
I mean to separate js logic by creating click handlers by selector.
This will be more flexible.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('.load-content').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="html/new.html" class="load-content">new</a>
<a href="html/old.html" class="load-content">old</a>
  
<div id="content"></div>
```

OR

```js
    $(function() {
      
      $('.load-content').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).data('url'));
        return false;
      });
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <a href="" data-url="html/new.html" class="load-content">new</a>
    <a href="" data-url="html/old.html" class="load-content">old</a>
      
    <div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: but i think your solution always depends on a click? I want to call it from a function as well as i just edited

Comment: You can bind this function to any event.

Comment: But I'm not having an event or a click. It just has to reload the new side after it is finished, which ist working on the click.